# Best way to send from php a variable to javascript, using laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

right now I'm sending a json from laravel to the View and populating a form, the problem is that I need to do certain modifications based in that data from javascript.
Right now I use an Ajax request to ask for the exact data from the server, I think thats a little repetitive, and I know I can do something like (var data = {{$data}}) and use it in my js file.

My question is, what is the best solution? Make an ajax call or make the variable directly from the view, I don't know if make the variable from the view is a bad practice or not.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should make the question a little clearer and include your code so we can see what your trying to accomplish

Comment: I'm between doing this:                                           <script type="text/javascript">
  var info = {{$dist}};  //Here I declare the variable info that I use in my js file.
</script>
                                                                        OR do this:  $.getJSON(location.href, {
               ajax: 'true'
             }, function(json, textStatus) {
               var info = json[0]; //Same variable                          What is the best practice?

Answer (score 8):

Here is one solution to pass javascript variables.
http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=2767

In Controller

```
// controller
$js_config = array(
    'BASE' => URL::base(),
    'FACEBOOK_APP' => Config::get('application.facebook_app')
);

return View::make('bla')
    ->with('js_config', $js_config);
```

In View

```
<script>
var config = <?php echo json_encode($js_config) ?>;

alert(config.BASE);
alert(config.FACEBOOK_APP.id);
alert(config.FACEBOOK_APP.channel_url);
</script>
```

Libraries are also available for that purpose

https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

```
public function index()
{
    JavaScript::put([
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'user' => User::first(),
        'age' => 29
    ]);

    return View::make('hello');
}
```

There are multiple approaches for this problem